# Как настроить сборку Андроид приложения в Gitlab с подтягиванием либы, собираемой в другом репо

Tags: android, gitlab, build, gitlab-ci, непрерывная-интеграция

Имеем Андроид приложение с либой на плюсах, которая собирается в другом репозитории.

В данный момент CI в gitlab настроен так, что в репо с Андроид приложением собирается .apk, но либа заменяется вручную (билдится в CI в другом репо, скачивается из артефактов, заменяется локально и пушится в соответсвующую ветку с приложением).

Как можно переписать CI приложения, чтобы либа, собираемая в соседнем репо, подтягивалась и заменялась автоматом при сборке приложения?

В идеале - запускаю пайп, в нем указываю ветку либы из соседнего репо --> собирается либа из соседнего репо на нужной мне ветке и далее собирается приложение уже с этой либой.